# Select query to ignore the data which exist in multiple records but with different value in one column

Tags: sql

I have following set of data, which i am getting using some inner query-

```
|Order|Party|Party Status|
|1    | P1  | COMP       |
|1    | P2  | NOTCOMP    |
|2    | P3  | COMP       |
|2    | P1  | COMP       |
|1    | P3  | NOTCOMP    |
|3    | P6  | COMP       |
```

I want to write a query which will retrieve only those orders for which all the parties have COMP status. If for a order any of the party have NOTCOMP status it should not return the order in the select query.

```
Expected output of from the above query would be - 
Order  - 2 & 3
```

Because for Orders 1 party P2 and P3 has status as NOTCOMP.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use of `not exists`

```
select * from table t
where not exists (
    select 1 from table t1
    where t1.order = t.order and t1.status <> 'COMP'
)
```

If, you don't want to go with `NOT IN`, `NOT Exists` or any other kind of `sub-query` or `joins`, then you could also do `GROUP BY` and filter via `HAVING` clause

```
select OrderR
from table t
group by OrderR
having sum(case when Party_Status <> 'COMP' then 1 else 0 end) = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one and suppose table1 is the table that you got after using the inner query that is producing the above dataset.

```
SELECT OrderR 
FROM Table1
WHERE OrderR NOT IN (
                    SELECT OrderR
                    FROM Table1
                    WHERE Party_Status = 'NOTCOMP'
                   )
GROUP BY OrderR
```

For demo please follow the below link:

> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8120c2/1

Comment: This result is coming from an inner query, I won't be able to reference it inside the not in or not exist clause. Or is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

--USING CROSS APPLY.
CREATE TABLE #ST_TAB([ORDER] INT,PARTY CHAR(3),[PARTY STATUS] CHAR(10))

INSERT INTO #ST_TAB
VALUES
(1,'P1','COMP'),
(1,'P2','NONCOMP'),
(1,'P3','NONCOMP'),
(2,'P3','COMP'),
(2,'P1','COMP')
,(1,'P3','NONCOMP'),
(3,'P6','COMP')

SELECT DISTINCT T1.[ORDER] FROM 
                    (

```
                SELECT  [Order]
```

FROM #ST_TAB S1
WHERE [PARTY STATUS]='COMP'    ) T1
CROSS APPLY
(
 SELECT [ORDER]
                    FROM #ST_TAB S
                    WHERE LTRIM(RTRIM([PARTY STATUS])) = 'NONCOMP' AND T1.[ORDER]<>S.[ORDER] ) T2